# Jasper Report - Subreport only printed first time

Tags: conditional-statements, jasper-reports, subreport

My problem is related with subreports primary, my configuration is the following:

I have a main report as shown in the image:
[image: main report]

Trueness associated subreport:

[image: trueness associated report]

And each of the 4 last reports has the same structure, a page header and a detail.

[image: each individual four last subreports]

the main report sends the parameter wavelength to its subreports and all the DataSources with all the info, and the last report has a conditional print detail:

```
$F{wavelength}.intValue()==$P{wavelength}.intValue()
```

Each DataSource "Bean" has wavelength as parameter and each **ChX** information.

---

When executing the application it generates 6 TruenessReports for Wavelenghts: (405,450,...,690), and 48 SubReports of each type (absorvance, reference, abs_error, rel_error).

The Report generated is the following (sorry but cannot generate one right now)

```
Wavelength: 405

Absorvances
Ch1  Ch2  Ch3  Ch4  Ch5  Ch6  Ch7  Ch8  Ch9  Ch10  Ch11  Ch12
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
Reference Absorvances
Ch1  Ch2  Ch3  Ch4  Ch5  Ch6  Ch7  Ch8  Ch9  Ch10  Ch11  Ch12
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
Absorvances Error
Ch1  Ch2  Ch3  Ch4  Ch5  Ch6  Ch7  Ch8  Ch9  Ch10  Ch11  Ch12
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
Relative Errors
Ch1  Ch2  Ch3  Ch4  Ch5  Ch6  Ch7  Ch8  Ch9  Ch10  Ch11  Ch12
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0


Wavelength: 450

Absorvances

Reference Absorvances

Absorvances Error

Relative Errors


....

Wavelength: 690

Absorvances

Reference Absorvances

Absorvances Error

Relative Errors
```

So, only the first time the last 4 subreports are printed, the next ones (in my case 5 other wavelengths) it does not print anything, and there is data for **its own** associated wavelength.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: i have the same issue, but no solution yet